# Key Error in multilevel Dict, even though key is in dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My end goal is to create a `pandas DataFrame` from a multilevel dict [as seen in this tutorial](https://stmorse.github.io/journal/espn-fantasy-v3.html). However, I am receiving a KeyError stating that one of the keys is not in the dict. Here is a subset of the multilevel dict:

```
{
    "draftDetail": {
        "drafted": True,
        "inProgress": False
    },
    "gameId": 1,
    "id": 862068,
    "schedule": [
        {
            "away": {
                "adjustment": 0.0,
                "cumulativeScore": {
                    "losses": 0,
                    "statBySlot": NULL,
                    "ties": 0,
                    "wins": 0
                },
                "pointsByScoringPeriod": {
                    "1": 126.82
                },
                "teamId": 1,
                "tiebreak": 0.0,
                "totalPoints": 126.82
            },
            "home": {
                "adjustment": 0.0,
                "cumulativeScore": {
                    "losses": 0,
                    "statBySlot": NULL,
                    "ties": 0,
                    "wins": 0
                },
                "pointsByScoringPeriod": {
                    "1": 115.52
                },
                "teamId": 15,
                "tiebreak": 0.0,
                "totalPoints": 115.52
            },
            "id": 0,
            "matchupPeriodId": 1,
            "playoffTierType": "NULL",
            "winner": "AWAY"
        },
        {
            "away": {
                "adjustment": 0.0,
                "cumulativeScore": {
                    "losses": 0,
                    "statBySlot": NULL,
                    "ties": 0,
                    "wins": 0
                },
                "pointsByScoringPeriod": {
                    "1": 183.4
                },
                "teamId": 16,
                "tiebreak": 0.0,
                "totalPoints": 183.4
            },
            "home": {
                "adjustment": 0.0,
                "cumulativeScore": {
                    "losses": 0,
                    "statBySlot": NULL,
                    "ties": 0,
                    "wins": 0
                },
                "pointsByScoringPeriod": {
                    "1": 115.08
                },
                "teamId": 6,
                "tiebreak": 0.0,
                "totalPoints": 115.08
            },
            "id": 1,
            "matchupPeriodId": 1,
            "playoffTierType": "NULL",
            "winner": "AWAY"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then to create the df I'm using the below code:

```
df = [[
        game['matchupPeriodId'],
        game['home']['teamId'], game['home']['totalPoints'],
        game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints']
    ] for game in d['schedule']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Week', 'Team1', 'Score1', 'Team2', 'Score2', 'PlayoffTier'])
df.head()
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-65-adda3411722d>", line 5, in <module>
    ] for game in d['schedule']] 

  File "<ipython-input-65-adda3411722d>", line 5, in <listcomp>
    ] for game in d['schedule']] 

KeyError: 'away'
```

I've also tried to see if the key can be identified in the dict using:

```
if 'away' in d['schedule']:
    print('will execute')
else:
    print('wont execute')
```

which is returning wont execute.

Any suggestions on how to fix the error? For further context, I'm connecting to ESPN's Fantasy Football API to initially retrieve the data, and can share the code preceding the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) The printed representation of "d" is syntactically incorrect (missing closing bracket). (2) After fixing this the shown code doesn't produce the shown error.

Comment: Hey Michael, sorry I copy and pasted a subset of the dict. If it's more helpful, I can include the entire dict, but it's rather long.

Comment: Better not. But you can make a try-except block around the failing part, unroll the list comprehension to a normal for-loop and print content of `game` in the except part to narrow down which data makes it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to handle what to do when there is no "away" key. This is caused by the playoff bracket having a bye for 2 teams:

```
import requests
import pprint
import pandas as pd


#set the leagueID and year info for ESPN league:

league_id = 123456 (example to not give out private league info)
year = 2019

#set the url with params and cookies:

url = "https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/leagueHistory/" + \
      str(league_id) + "?seasonId=" + str(year)

SWID = "{BF2E3A9D-093E-425E-B4A2-7DD5D4ABCAB1}"

Cookies = "AEB8LR5rfxLehSJOeku1TOugWAJfebsbk%2F5wBfrldGZ5svoy8Au1Ic%2BZX6P1y%2BWMcScgyoyuwvoRDv%2FqDfIAQRnjd9amDBSdk4Nze4hdTlTUFAa7Y9QJL4IAY0YNtrSPlFjVDGRugXRn309EpQeVWj5akI75GQjx%2FoGLtQ30UHzEdk4A8qBuxqjJ3oy9eIDPYOooncwVJ0AxbAAwuhSpqoEZOHwn8XAoCKyp4yU6H5HvyEGBUU9DiSHV6nvjLCZahWSAfd3TaY%2FMDQUutdaK5HcC"

#make request to API
r = requests.get(url, params={"view":"mMatchupScore"}, cookies={"swid":SWID, "espn_2": Cookies})
#set request as JSON
d = r.json()[0]
#explore JSON formatting
print(d)
#following the tutorial, create dataframe from MMatchScore end point:



#Option 1: insert the away key with teamId and totalPoints values of null

import numpy as np
for each in d['schedule']:
    if 'away' not in each.keys():
        each.update({'away': {'teamId':np.nan, 'totalPoints':np.nan}})

df = [[
        game['matchupPeriodId'],
        game['home']['teamId'], game['home']['totalPoints'],
        game['away']['teamId'], game['away']['totalPoints'],
        game['playoffTierType']
    ] for game in d['schedule']] #returning keyerror: 'away'

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Week', 'Team1', 'Score1', 'Team2', 'Score2', 'PlayoffTier'])
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
df.head()

df.shape


# Option 2: use a regular for loop in stead of list comprehension to deal with 
# if "away" not in key

weekList = []
team1List = []
score1List = []
team2List = []
score2List = []
playoffTierList = []

for game in d['schedule']:
    playoffTierList.append(game['playoffTierType'])
    weekList.append(game['matchupPeriodId'])
    team1List.append(game['home']['teamId'])
    score1List.append(game['home']['totalPoints'])
    
    if 'away' not in game.keys():
        team2List.append(np.nan)
        score2List.append(np.nan)
    else:
        team2List.append(game['away']['teamId'])
        score2List.append(game['away']['totalPoints'])
        
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'Week':weekList, 'Team1':team1List, 'Score1': score1List, 
                   'Team2':team2List, 'Score2':score2List, 'PlayoffTier':playoffTierList})
df['Type'] = ['Regular' if w<14 else 'Playoff' for w in df['Week']]
df.head()

df.shape
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
    Week  Team1  Score1  Team2  Score2                 PlayoffTier     Type
0      1     15  115.52    1.0  126.82                        NONE  Regular
1      1      6  115.08   16.0  183.40                        NONE  Regular
2      1      2  155.32    5.0  129.60                        NONE  Regular
3      1     17  133.86   13.0  109.04                        NONE  Regular
4      1     11  107.26    7.0  133.02                        NONE  Regular
5      1     12  108.14    8.0   66.26                        NONE  Regular
6      2      1  106.66   16.0  157.06                        NONE  Regular
7      2      5  102.80   15.0  119.56                        NONE  Regular
8      2      2  116.38    6.0  121.72                        NONE  Regular
9      2     13  104.76    7.0  111.52                        NONE  Regular
10     2      8  104.30   17.0  118.30                        NONE  Regular
11     2     12   83.62   11.0  104.02                        NONE  Regular
12     3      5   92.20    1.0  131.20                        NONE  Regular
13     3     16  162.54    2.0  116.48                        NONE  Regular
14     3     15  153.64    6.0  131.22                        NONE  Regular
15     3      8  114.84   13.0  113.34                        NONE  Regular
16     3      7  141.06   12.0  114.02                        NONE  Regular
17     3     17  123.36   11.0  123.32                        NONE  Regular
18     4      1  122.58    2.0  142.18                        NONE  Regular
19     4      6   96.84    5.0  117.10                        NONE  Regular
20     4     15   92.70   16.0  137.72                        NONE  Regular
21     4     13   98.10   12.0  124.38                        NONE  Regular
22     4     11   84.20    8.0  153.10                        NONE  Regular
23     4     17   62.78    7.0  108.10                        NONE  Regular
24     5      6  116.24    1.0  139.14                        NONE  Regular
25     5      2  119.74   15.0  193.54                        NONE  Regular
26     5      5  158.88   16.0  115.62                        NONE  Regular
27     5     11   82.04   13.0   92.62                        NONE  Regular
28     5     12  139.00   17.0  121.90                        NONE  Regular
29     5      8  118.92    7.0  130.14                        NONE  Regular
..   ...    ...     ...    ...     ...                         ...      ...
67    12     17   51.14   15.0  123.02                        NONE  Regular
68    12      7  125.68   16.0  119.52                        NONE  Regular
69    12      8   96.00    5.0  105.80                        NONE  Regular
70    12     12  165.98    2.0  128.06                        NONE  Regular
71    12     11   90.66    6.0  136.04                        NONE  Regular
72    13     15  108.24   13.0   81.44                        NONE  Regular
73    13     16  118.22   17.0  127.48                        NONE  Regular
74    13      5  109.90    7.0   82.22                        NONE  Regular
75    13      2  130.94    8.0  149.90                        NONE  Regular
76    13      6  105.86   12.0   91.50                        NONE  Regular
77    13      1  139.22   11.0   79.86                        NONE  Regular
78    14      7  148.16    NaN     NaN             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
79    14     16  125.16    1.0   76.00             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
80    14      5  153.42    6.0  120.96             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
81    14     15  144.68    NaN     NaN             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
82    14      2  149.00    8.0   90.10   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
83    14     12   85.62   17.0  129.72   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
84    14     11   91.34   13.0   67.16   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
85    15      7  182.56   16.0  165.62             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
86    15     15  148.62    5.0  136.62             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
87    15      1   88.42    6.0   99.48  WINNERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
88    15      2  136.68   17.0  121.90   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
89    15      8  145.04   11.0  112.60   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
90    15     12  125.40   13.0  123.02   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
91    16      7  123.42   15.0   80.16             WINNERS_BRACKET  Playoff
92    16      5  109.40   16.0  123.40  WINNERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
93    16      1  128.94    6.0  128.96  WINNERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
94    16      2  102.02    8.0   99.26   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
95    16     12   83.74   17.0  151.46   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff
96    16     11   84.46   13.0   80.04   LOSERS_CONSOLATION_LADDER  Playoff

[97 rows x 7 columns]
```